# How to curve an image without CSS

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas, php-gd

Guys i want to curve an image without using CSS. is there anyway to do it with HTML5 ,HTML5 canvas or php.
i was able to curve line but how curve an image.
can anybody give me a direction.

Comment: What does "curve" mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery plugin for curved corners;
http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/
for curving corners you can use javascript as below or CSS syntax.

```
    $('.myBox').corner({
    tl: { radius: 8 }, tr: { radius: 8 }, bl: { radius: 8 }, br: { radius: 8 }, antiAlias: true 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
selector {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
```